# chart.js - dynamically added chart makes previous ones disappear

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Basically

Whenever I call addData like

```
addData("TEST1", 1);
```

or

```
addData("TEST2", 1);
```

then I'm checking whether chart named "TEST1" already exists and if it does then I return chart object and if it doesn't then I create new

and then I insert data on it

and it works to the point that when I create e.g 2nd chart, then first one disappears

but why?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-QSkVNOCYLtj73J4hbmVoOV6KVZuMluZlioC+trLpewV8qMjsWqlIQvkn1KGX2StWvPMdWGBqim1xlC8krl1EKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="charts">

</div>


<script>
var dict = new Object();

function addData(name, data) 
{
    var chart = dict[name];
    if (chart == undefined)
    {
        console.log("adding chart:"  + name);
        chart = AddChart(name);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("skipping chart creation:"  + name);
    }
        
    chart.data.labels.push(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => 
    {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}


function AddChart(name)
{
    const data = 
    {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: name,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [],
        }]
    };

    const config = 
    {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options:
        {
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
        }
    };

    var cont = document.getElementById("charts");
    cont.innerHTML += `<div width="140px" height="140px"><canvas id="chart_${name}"></canvas></div>`;

    const myChart = new Chart
    (
        document.getElementById(`chart_${name}`).getContext('2d'),
        config
    );

    dict[name] = myChart;

    console.log("added");
    console.log(dict);
    return dict[name];
}

addData("TEST1", 1);
addData("TEST2", 1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me and I don't know why the first chart is not shown. Looking at the `DOM` in Chrome DevTools, I see that both `canvas` are correctly added to the `div`'s `innerHTML`.

The problem can be solved. Instead of using the `div`'s `innerHTML`, you can use  [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for creating the child `div` and it's `canvas`, then [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to add the new structure to the `DOM` as follows:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'chart_' + name);
canvas.setAttribute('width', '250');
canvas.setAttribute('height', '200');
let canvasContainer = document.createElement('div');
canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);
document.getElementById("charts").appendChild(canvasContainer);
```

The same could be done throgh two lines of code by using the jQuery `.append()` function as follows:

```
let chartContainer = $(`<div><canvas id="chart_${name}" width="140px" height="140px"></canvas></div>`);
$('#charts').append(chartContainer);
```

Please take a look at your amended code below and see how it works.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-QSkVNOCYLtj73J4hbmVoOV6KVZuMluZlioC+trLpewV8qMjsWqlIQvkn1KGX2StWvPMdWGBqim1xlC8krl1EKQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="charts"></div>

<script>
  let dict = new Object();

  function addData(name, data) {
    let chart = dict[name];
    if (!chart) {    
      chart = addChart(name);
      dict[name] = chart;
    }
    chart.data.labels.push(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => dataset.data.push(data));
    chart.update();
  }

  function addChart(name) {
    let data = {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [{
        label: name,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [],
      }]
    };    
    let config = {
      type: 'line',
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
      }
    };
    
    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'chart_' + name);
    canvas.setAttribute('width', '250');
    canvas.setAttribute('height', '200');
    let canvasContainer = document.createElement('div');
    canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);
    document.getElementById("charts").appendChild(canvasContainer);

    return new Chart(`chart_${name}`, config );   
  }

  addData("TEST1", 1);
  addData("TEST1", 2);
  addData("TEST2", 1);
  addData("TEST2", 3);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, it works fine, but I will later want to drop that dependency on jQuery, so I'll have to reverse engineer that append

Comment: @Axelly: I updated my answer with code that has no dependency on jQuery.